# Call multiple bean method in primefaces simultaneously

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am building a web application using primefaces-4.0. I wanted to call two bean methods simultaneously on click of command button. I tried it by using **remoteCommand**.

```
<p:commandButton value="Submit" ajax="false"
                        actionListener="#{userBean.execute}"
                        onclick="callCorrelation()">
                    </p:commandButton>
                    <p:remoteCommand name="correlation" update="correlationDialog"
                        actionListener="#{userBean.correlation}" />
```

Java Script function :

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).callCorrelation(function() {
        correlation ();
    });           
</script>
</head>
```

But it did not work.

Is there any other way to call two bean methods simultaneously?

Comment: You can set one method for the `action` attribute and one for the `actionListener` attribute.

Answer (score 6):

Your concrete problem is caused because you've turned off ajax by `ajax="false"`. This will create a synchronous form submit which makes it impossible to fire an ajax request along. If you remove `ajax="false"`, then it will likely work, but you've still a race condition if the one method depends on the result of the other. It's not defined which one would be executed first.

Better just use a single command component. You can use `action` and `actionListener` together. The `action` is intented for business actions. The `actionListener` is intented for preparing of business actions. If you need more action listeners, just nest a `<f:actionListener>` or perhaps a `<f:setPropertyActionListener>`.

```
<p:commandButton value="Submit"
    actionListener="#{userBean.correlation}"
    action="#{userBean.execute}"
    update="correlationDialog" />
```

#### See also:

- [Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener/)

Comment: Thanks Balus..I have tried by removing off ajax but it did not worked.

Comment: I also tried with single command component that you have suggested,but in this approach it is executing correlation method first followed by execute method..But I want to execute both methods at the same time not one by one...So is there any other way to execute both methods at the same time?

Comment: Why exactly would you want to do that? Do you realize that you need 2 threads for that? The above answer just executes the both methods in 1 enduser interaction.

Comment: Yes exactly..I need to threads that will run in parallel..But before implementing threading I am looking for some other option..How to run two bean methods simultaneously in JSF without implementing Threading.

Comment: Actually the problem is If I marge these two methods and create a single bean method that executes after click on submit button..it takes too much time to execute and load the xhtml page.To minimize this loading and execution time I converted this single method in two different methods.

Comment: Just invoke 1 method and let Java spawn 2 threads. EJB's `@Asynchronous` is very helpful in this.