# One button, multiple actions

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have two beans to be called and I want to use one button to call them. How to do this?

Here is my try:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p:inputTextarea rows="6" cols="33" autoResize="false"
                     value="#{uploadText.text}" maxlength="174" />
</h:form>

<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p:messages showDetail="true" />
    <p:panelGrid columns="2" style=" width:30px;">
        <h:outputLabel id="image" value="Select Image: *" />
        <p:fileUpload value="#{uploadImage.file}" mode="simple"
                      allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" />
    </p:panelGrid>

    <h:commandButton action="#{uploadImage.upload}" value="Submit">
        <f:actionListener binding="#{uploadText.upload}" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

But it throws this error:

```
/calendar.xhtml @109,55 binding="#{uploadText.upload}": The class 'textView.UploadText' does not have the property 'upload'.
```

Only because I'm using binding here :

```
<h:commandButton action="#{uploadImage.upload}" value="Submit">
    <f:actionListener binding="#{uploadText.upload}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

It says The class `textView.UploadText` does not have the property 'upload' which is not true! I tried `actionListner` as well but it's not working.

Here is uploadtext class:

```
public class UploadText implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String text;

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public void upload() {

        if (text != null) {

            try {
                String f_username = JloginDAO.user;

                Connection con = DBconnection.getConnection();
                PreparedStatement pre = con.prepareStatement("insert into upload_text (text,user_idt) values(?, (SELECT id from users WHERE username = ?))");
                pre.setString(1, text);
                pre.setString(2, f_username);

                pre.executeUpdate();
                System.out.println("Inserting Successfully!");
                pre.close();
                FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Succesful", text + " is uploaded.");
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception-File Upload." + e.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Please select image!!");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show the class as well?

Comment: Please see edited post above @HoXa

Comment: Upload is method not a property, don't you have to add parenthesis? action="#{uploadImage.upload()}"

Comment: You should use the `type` attribute of `<f:actionListener>` instead to refer to its implementation (a fully qualified class name) which `ActionListner` is implemented on or just the `actionListener` attribute of `<h:commandButton>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call multiple bean method in primefaces simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18850322/call-multiple-bean-method-in-primefaces-simultaneously)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [documentatnon for `f:actionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/actionListener.html), you'll see that `binding` attribute must evaluate to `javax.faces.event.ActionListener`. This means that `UploadText` class needs to implement `javax.faces.event.ActionListener` interface (you have an example on [this blog](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-actionlistener-example/)).

The easiest option (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16374302/4074715)) is to add a method like this to your bean:

```
public ActionListener createActionListener() {
    return new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void processAction(ActionEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {
            System.out.println("here I have both the event object, and access to the enclosing bean");
        }
    };
}
```

and target this method from `f:actionListener`

```
<f:actionListener binding="#{uploadText.createActionListener()}"/>
```

Using this technique, you can call multiple methods with single button.