# Primefaces jasper report and navigate to other page

Tags: forms, jsf-2, primefaces, navigation, jasper-reports

Using primefaces 5.3, on form submit button i need to update the database with the form values and open a jasper report in a new tab while source page should navigate to some other page. Currently I have two separate buttons that are doing the job but click to the second button is redundant which i want to avoid.
Below is the testing code
Backing bean method to update database

```
public String createVoucher(){  
    initAllVariables();

    try{
            tempSessionVars();
            this.item=fillVoucher();
            this.create();
            List<Voucherdetails> cashvdlist = new ArrayList<>(this.item.getVoucherdetailsCollection());
            printflag=true;
            iterateSelection();
            profilelist=new ArrayList();
            profilemap.clear();
            testlist=new ArrayList();
            testmap.clear(); 

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "/pfpages/aaPatient3/wizardpages/PatientCreate.xhtml"; //After execution return to this page
}
```

Method to process jasper report

```
public void printFirstCashSlipAfterRegistration(){
    initAllVariables();
    List<Voucherdetails> cashvdlist = new ArrayList<>(this.item.getVoucherdetailsCollection());
    String testprofilecashsliplist=AReportPrint.convertVoucherdetailsToString(cashvdlist);
    try{
        AReportPrint.printCashSlip(testprofilecashsliplist, item);
    }catch(NullPointerException npe){
        System.err.println("Null pointer exception at createVoucher during printCashSlip" + npe.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Currently in my xhtml page i have created 2 forms each having a separate command button for processing above 2 methods

```
<h:panelGroup id="selectedtestpanel3">
<h:form id="SelectedTests3" >     
    <p:selectOneMenu id="CompanyPanelsList" value="#{aTestRegController.selectedpanel}" required="true" converter="#{pfpagesConverter}">
        <p:ajax event="change"  listener="#{aTestRegController.onCompanyPanelChange}"
                update="patientRegWizard:displayprices"
                />
        <f:selectItems value="#{aTestRegController.panellist}" var="panel" itemValue="#{panel}"/>

    </p:selectOneMenu>
    <p:dataTable id="selectedTestDataTable3" value="#{aTestRegController.testprofilelist}" var="seltestprofile" 
                 rowKey="#{aTestRegController.selectedToString(seltestprofile)}" tableStyle="width:auto" resizableColumns="true"
                 selectionMode="single" selection="#{aTestRegController.selected}" style="vertical-align:top;"
                 >
        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{aTestRegController.testprofilePull(aTestRegController.selected)}" 
                update="patientRegWizard:SelectedTests3, patientRegWizard:displayprices"/>

        <p:column headerText="Test/Profile Name" width="10">
            <h:outputText value="#{aTestRegController.selectedTestProfileName(seltestprofile)}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Price" width="10">
            <h:outputText value="#{aTestRegController.selectedTestProfilePrice(seltestprofile)}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Container" width="10">
            <h:outputText value="#{aTestRegController.selectedTestProfileContainer(seltestprofile)}"/>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>

    <p:commandButton id="saveReg2" icon="ui-icon-plus"   value="Save Test Registration01" 
        action="#{aTestRegController.createVoucher()}" 
        disabled="#{empty aTestRegController.testprofilelist}"                                       
        update="patientRegWizard:printform growl" process="@form"
    />

</h:form>
```

```
<h:panelGroup>
<h:form id="printform" >
    <p:commandButton id="printSlip" value="Print Registration Slip" 
        actionListener="#{aTestRegController.printFirstCashSlipAfterRegistration()}" 
        process="@form"
        ajax="false" onclick="this.form.target='_blank'"
    />
</h:form>
```

Can the action on these 2 buttons be merged?

Edit:
I've tried BalusC solution with action and actionListener from [Call multiple bean method in primefaces simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18850322/call-multiple-bean-method-in-primefaces-simultaneously)
but since calling Jasper Report method requires Ajax="false" therefore both methods fire but actionListener fires twice causing exception in database and action does not navigate to the action's outcome.

```
<p:commandButton id="saveReg2" icon="ui-icon-plus"   value="Save Test Registration01" 
                        actionListener="#{aTestRegController.createVoucher()}" 
                        action="#{aTestRegController.printFirstCashSlipAfterRegistration()}" 
                        disabled="#{empty aTestRegController.testprofilelist}"                                       
                        update="patientRegWizard:printform growl" 
                        ajax="false" onclick="this.form.target='_blank'"
                    />
```

Comment: _"Can the action on these 2 buttons be merged? "_ : Sure, server side...

Comment: Tried many things but somehow could not figure out how to do it.

Comment: I'm just a jasper report user and not jsf-2 expert but probably I would have done a mapping for the report (url mapping in web.xml), then you launch action that saves, goes to new page, the new page launches a javascript to open a new window, with the correct parameters to display the report... Hence assuming that you need to save before you display report...